# Adding previous values of a directory size recursively

Tags: c, recursion

I'm writing a C program that will, when given a directory, recursively go through all subdirectories and get the size of all the files. Basically, mimicking the "du" function.

Thing is, I can't seem to be able to get add the files from the subdirectory to its parent directory.

```
    if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        recurSize(file);
```

The above is my main loop, where I would make sure it skips . and .. in order to counter an infinite loop. Then set the file name and add the size of all the files in the subdirectory. How would I go about adding the size from `size += statbuf.st_blocks / 2;` to `recurSize(file);` (which is the recursive function)?

Example of my output:

```
116 ../A2
4 ../bellow/mellow
8 ../bellow
76 ../A1
4 ../submit/temp
84 ../submit
292 ..
```

Expected output:

```
116 ../A2
4 ../bellow/mellow
12 ../bellow
76 ../A1
4 ../submit/temp
88 ../submit
292 ..
```

The reason the `292 ..` works as it should is because of a workaround I attempted but that only seems to work on the largest main directory, anyone know how I can apply it to everything?

I'm going to keep working on this, and if I figure it out I'll update this for whoever's interested.

EDIT: Thank you for getting it, yeah simply returning the value back seems to have fixed it, thank you :)

Comment: Is that some software announcement for an already existing software? Do you have any **specific** question?

Comment: @Olaf It's a personal program, my question is how do I allow new values of size to move up along the recursive ladder.
i.e. /bellow should also add the value of /bellow/mellow to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
    recurSize(file);
```

does not return the size of what was found in the new recursion. You need to have it return the size that it found.

```
if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
    // Showing as two statements for clarity.
    newsize = recurSize(file);
    size += newsize;
```

Then at the end of `recurSize()` you need

```
return size;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I should have figured it out myself, so thank you for helping me out :)